# Just downloaded TextMate, can't import modules

Tags: python, module, matplotlib, textmate

I am trying to use python in order to simulate social networks, this requires matplotlib.pyplot, networkx and xlrd. Everything works fine from terminal, IDLE or X11 but when I try to use TextMate `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `import xlrd` throws up ImportError: No module named... however `import networkx` works fine!

I downloaded python via EPD and so matplotlib came ready baked in however I got xlrd and networkx with easy_install.

Anybody have an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell TextMate which Python to use.  One way to do that is to define the shell variable `TM_PYTHON` with an absolute path to the Python interpreter you want to use.  In the TextMate menu, select `Preferences`, then the `Advanced` tab, then the `Shell Variables` tab, and click `+` to add the new variable.  If you don't know the absolute path to the EPD Python, type `which python` (or whatever you are using to start Python) in a Terminal shell window.